# Nuxt Setting the Page Title after API Call

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm looking to set my page's title and meta description after an API call is made. I've tried numerous way's but it's always returning `Undefined` for product. I can put a temp title such as `Loading` while it's calling the API but is this the best way for SEO?

```
  <script setup>
  const product = ref({});
  
  onMounted(async () => {
    const route = useRoute();
    const id = route.params.id;
    await getProduct(id);
  });

  async function getProduct(id) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/products/${id}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      product.value = data.item;
        // Call definePageMeta after setting product data
        definePageMeta({
            title: product.value
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  }
  </script>
```

I'm using `NuxtSEO` module.